# What will happen in case Bill is passed by the Parliament but not sent to President for approval?

Tags: president, constitution, parliament, india

Case specific to : India

What is the law/rule/protocol/convention in case when a bill is passed from both Houses of Parliament and is about to be sent to the President for his approval but is held back or say not sent!

We often read in books that Bill is approved by both the houses and assented by President thus becomes an Act without focusing on the inter linking steps in the journey.

Can someone clarify that who is the person who takes the passed bill to the President (a minister or some secretary) and what are the time limits of such a process.

Also in which source such details are mentioned.

Comment: Not sending the bill is unconstitutional  (Article 111) Unreasonable or indefinite delay would also be unlawful, under general common law interpretation of terms like "Shall be sent"